# Apache alias to a file in a virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to setup z-push which requires an alias `/Microsoft-Server-Activesync` that points to a file `index.php` in another directory outside of the VHost location. To test I setup a file in the same path and created the following

```
Alias /info /var/www/z-push/info.php
<Directory "/usr/share/z-push/">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

which doesn't work, but if I change the Alias to this

```
Alias /info.php /var/www/z-push/info.php
```

I can access it at the url `example.com/info.php`. Except I need to be able to have `example.com/info` for the ActiveSync stuff to work.

I assume I can fix this with a RewriteRule but I'm not having any luck with that.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

Here is my virtual host config :

```
SetEnv RAILS_ENV production

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite index to check for static
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [QSA]

# Rewrite to check for Rails cached page
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]

DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public/

<Directory /var/www/redmine/public/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync /var/www/z-push
<Directory "/usr/share/z-push">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce in lab, works fine. What is your Distro ?

Comment: Debian 7.4. The full vhost config is here http://pastebin.com/M08i9hZF.

Comment: Maybe i've found the culprit, give it a try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the culprit is this `rewrite` rule you have on top of your config file :

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

With this rule enabled, when you request `example.com/info` then the `.html` extension is added and your request becomes `example.com/info.html`.

And, of course, such a file does not exist. Extract from my log :

```
[error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/info.html
```

---

As it seems that this rewrite rule is needed by `Rails`, i won't suggest you to comment it out.

You could modify this rule, adding a rewrite condition, so that it will apply **only** if the requested page is **not** `/info` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/info
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

Comment: @Geoff Johnson Ok great ! I've updated your post with your config to make things more clear for others. In case you don't want (i cannot see any critical datas in this) tell me, i will delete it.